# Does apt update also update apt-get lists?

Tags: debian, apt

Do you need to run apt-get update for using apt-get if you already ran apt update and vice versa?

Comment: Both `apt` and `apt-get` use the same package database,  so updating with either one serves for both.

Answer (score 0):

apt provides all the same functions for package management as apt-get and it's faster / more user-friendly as described in this article: https://linuxhint.com/diff_apt_vs_aptget/

So basically, you can use both but apt might be best to use.